# Cannot get scope variable length when it was changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my HTML I have a `ng-init="find()"` that calls this function:

```
$scope.find = function()
{
    $scope.vehicles = Vehicles.query();
    $scope.vehiclesQtd = $scope.vehicles.length;
};
```

My vehicles are displayed in the view but `$scope.vehiclesQtd` is always `0`.

I add a watcher to change `$scope.vehiclesQtd` when I add or delete a vehicle:

```
$scope.$watch('vehicles', function()
{
    $scope.vehiclesQtd = $scope.vehicles.length;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.vehiclesQtd, null, 4));
});
```

The console is always returning `0` (and when I console `$scope.vehicles` the return is always `[]`) but my vehicles are being displayed.
I need to know the vehicle length to put a limit in the vehicle creation.

Comment: why can you not call the function in the controller instead of `ng-init`?  `ng-init` is a very specialized directive, and it gets misused very often, and this feels like another misuse (without seeing the full context, of course).

Comment: also, what is `Vehicles.query()`?  that looks like maybe a resource? and it seems like it's probably a promise?

Comment: @Claies 1. This controller is used in other places to manage other vehicle related stuff. In some places, don't makes sense to call `find()` or other functions that wasn't needed. 2. Yea, it's `$resource` and it is working very well. But I cannot understand what is going on now to get this information :/

Comment: that still doesn't make any sense;  if you are putting it in `ng-init`, then it is being called when the element is being initialized, which is exactly the same time that the controller is being initialized, except that `ng-init` is a directive and has timing conflicts.  Unless what you are saying is you are using this controller on more than one view (another bad practice), then you are still not giving a valid reason to use `ng-init` in this way, against it's documentation.

Comment: as for your `Vehicles` being a resource, `.query()` returns a promise, so you have to use `.then()` to wait for the promise to resolve before you can use the data.  The way it is written now, you are asking for the promise to start, then immediately setting the `vehiclesQtd` value, and then the actual data is returned sometime after that, meaning `vehiclesQtd` could never have the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$scope.vehicles = Vehicles.query();` is a http call which fetches result, as it is async call your `$scope.vehiclesQtd = $scope.vehicles.length;` is executed even before your http call is completed.

So to get the exact length add the `if(newVal !== oldVal){` in your watcher, as soon as your http call is completed and your service returns data to `$scope.vehicles` watcher will fire and if condition gets satisfied and now you can fetch the length.

```
$scope.find = function(){
    $scope.vehicles = Vehicles.query();// this is a http call which is async..
    $scope.vehiclesQtd = $scope.vehicles.length;// this line is executed even before your above line i.e http call is completed ..
};
```

You can simply do like below in your watcher

```
$scope.$watch('vehicles', function(newVal,oldVal){
     if(newVal !== oldVal){
         $scope.vehiclesQtd = $scope.vehicles.length;
         console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.vehiclesQtd, null, 4));
     }
});
```